# Function app giving exception HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I tried and tested my code on local everything works perfect.

But when I host it on Azure Function app getting below error.

```
 <h1> HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure </h1>

        <h2> Common causes of this issue: </h2>
        <ul>
            <li> The application failed to start </li>
            <li> The application started but then stopped </li>
            <li> The application started but threw an exception during startup </li>
        </ul>

        <h2> Troubleshooting steps: </h2>
        <ul>
            <li> Check the system event log for error messages </li>
            <li> Enable logging the application process' stdout messages </li>
            <li> Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect </li>
        </ul>
```

unable to understand what could be the issue?
in the logs also could not have any details.

simple HttpTrigget azure function which calls from Logic app after every 3 minutes.

```
        string response = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

    var myclassobj = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    myclassobj.mapping = new MappingClass();

    //map API JSON response to C# object
    MyClass.data details = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass.data>(response, myclassobj);
    var jsonstring = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(details);
    return new OkObjectResult(jsonstring);
```

Comment: Take a look at this github issue https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8980

Comment: I tried above all my code is clean

no references in my function project , no unwanted nugets , no connection string used its a simple code like updates question :(

Answer (score -1):

Hi there is an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8980) for this. For some people it was issue which registering dependencies and for some connection string format.